# Convert LocalDate to Date for targeting API 21

Tags: android, date, localdate

Trying to convert a LocalDate to Date using the following but getting this error:

`Call requires API level 26 (current min is 21): java.util.Date#from`

`val finalDate = Date.from(finalLocalDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())`

I cannot change the min SDK.

Just wondering that is the best way to do this?

Comment: To handle Dates on apps the best thing you can do is switching to [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library, which works with API >= 15

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `desugar_jdk_libs` to use Java 8 Date APIs. 
Docs and setup guide:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support